# Regex to match [any char][any digit]dot with an exception case

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex `[a-zA-Z0-9]\\.(.*)` to match:
[any character, any digit] followed by a dot and then followed by anything. For example e1.abc, `r11.xyz`, etc.

This works fine. However I have a case where if string is `e.abc` then it should not match i.e. only if it is `e.` then it should not match.

How do I modify my regex to handle this specific exclusion?

Comment: First get the matches, then in an `If` statement, use `if(string.startswith("e.")` to filter this case out.

Comment: The regex you have in your question does not allow for more than one char before the "."

Comment: @lonesome the OP wants regex

Comment: @ScaryWombat I just give OP another solution. OP just dont know if there is another way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify your regex by adding a negative lookahead assertion before the first pre-dot character.  This lookahead will ensure that this first letter is not `e`.  Here is the pattern:

```
.*(?!e)[a-zA-Z0-9]\.(.*)
```

**Sample code:**

```
String match = "a.abc";
if (match.matches(".*(?!e)[a-zA-Z0-9]\\.(.*)")) {
    System.out.println("match");
}
String noMatch = "e.abc";
if (noMatch.matches(".*(?!e)[a-zA-Z0-9]\\.(.*)")) {
    System.out.println("no match");
}
```

Note that I assume that there is only one dot in your string.  If not, then this answer would need to change.

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: I think the OP may want more than 1 char before the first "." The e1.abc, r11.xyz example.

Comment: Tim the King of Regex

Comment: Actually that Wiktor guy is the king of regex.  But he is asleep right now, so it's open season for us mere mortals :-)

Comment: I love when the SO gods are asleep :) @TimBiegeleisen congrats on 100K - I'll be there in about 20 years.

Answer (score 0):

Just get all the matches using your current regex, then just add an `If` statement as followings:

```
    String test="e.this is test";
if(!test.startsWith("e."){
    //Do someting
  }
```

Comment: Why have an if statement if you can do it all with a regex?

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis maybe because it will work just fine? hehe

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis It only needs two extra lines while the above answer needs a lot of additional lines and looks very complex while my answer is clean, short, easy to use and easy to understand.

Comment: Your code is not even complete. Not the DVer by the way.

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis Just showed OP what to do. OP can modify it. He or she only needs to be notified there is such a thing as `.startsWith()`

Comment: so when you go into a shop and ask for `milk` you are happy if the shopkeeper gives you `water`?

Comment: @ScaryWombat cherry picking. The OP may thought the only solution is through regex while it has a way easier way to tackle it. Stop annoying me. pffft.

Comment: We don't have `milk` , but we have something that `.startsWith("milk")` j.k.